# If hatred rises, How far I am to Nirvana?

Tags: buddha

I saw in Indian T.V. serial Buddha saying that if hatred rises then know that you are far from Nirvana, is it true?
 Is there any other way Buddha described a way where one can see his current position in the journey to nirvana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw in Indian T.V. serial Buddha saying that if hatred rises then know that you are far from Nirvana, is it true?

When you attain Nirvana both unwholesome or wholesome roots do not arise, you have also have eliminated the [Five hindrances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances). Therefore, if any roots or hindrances appear in your mind then you are not in Nirvana. If there is a increase of roots, particularly unwholesome roots and then this can be viewed as moving away from Nirvana, hence moving away from Nirvana may be the right way to put it. Hatred has the root of [dosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvesha_(Buddhism)) and also linked to Ill Will (vyāpāda). More on this see [The Roots of Good and Evil](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/roots_goodevil.pdf), by Nyanaponika [Thera and The Five Mental Hindrances and Their Conquest](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html) Selected Texts from the Pali Canon and the Commentaries compiled and translated by Nyanaponika Thera

> Is there any other way Buddha described a way where one can see his current position in the journey to nirvana?

There are many measures of progress but the most reliable is equanimity as if this is present then unwholesome roots of aversion and craving does not arise. More on this see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13182/295) and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3467/295).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say what "far from nirnava" means since nirvana isn't easily compared to other states of mind. We could say that you are close to nirvana if you reach one of the [four stages of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment). Freedom from hatred only occurs at the final stage when you become fully enlightened; however, an Anagami is free from ill-will so any hatred would not cause him to wish harm on any being.

These stages of enlightenment are one measure of progress on the path, although they are very advanced levels of progress.